# Why are my jTextFields getting the wrong values?

Tags: java, jtextfield

AddSongDialog

```
public static javax.swing.JTextField getjTextFieldArtist() {
    return jTextFieldArtist;
}

public void setjTextFieldArtist(javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldArtist) {
    this.jTextFieldArtist = jTextFieldArtist;
}

public static javax.swing.JTextField getjTextFieldFileName() {
    return jTextFieldFileName;
}

public void setjTextFieldFileName(javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldFileName) {
    this.jTextFieldFileName = jTextFieldFileName;
}

public static javax.swing.JTextField getjTextFieldSongGenre() {
    return jTextFieldSongGenre;
}

public void setjTextFieldSongGenre(javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldSongGenre) {
    this.jTextFieldSongGenre = jTextFieldSongGenre;
}

public static javax.swing.JTextField getjTextFieldSongName() {
    return jTextFieldSongName;
}

public void setjTextFieldSongName(javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldSongName) {
    this.jTextFieldSongName = jTextFieldSongName;
}


}
```

Main Form

```
 private void jButtonAddSongActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
 AddSongDialog addSongDialog = new AddSongDialog(this, true);
 addSongDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
 addSongDialog.setVisible(true);

 String fileName = AddSongDialog.getjTextFieldFileName().getText();
 String songName = AddSongDialog.getjTextFieldSongName().getText();
 String songGenre = AddSongDialog.getjTextFieldSongGenre().getText();
 String songArtist = AddSongDialog.getjTextFieldArtist().getText();

 Song songInfo = new Song(songName, fileName, songGenre, songArtist);
 Song files = new Song(fileName, fileName, fileName, fileName);

 songs.add(songInfo);
 songFileLibrary.add(files);

 WriteToFile();

 updatejListMusicLibrary();
 updatejListFileLibrary();
}                                              



private void jListMusicLibraryMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                               
    JList ListMusicLibrary = (JList)evt.getSource();

    if(evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
        currentMusicLibraryIndex = 
ListMusicLibrary.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());

        //Song s = songs.get(jListMusicLibrary.getSelectedIndex());
        SongInfoDialog sid = new SongInfoDialog(this,true);


        if(ListMusicLibrary.getSelectedIndex() != -1)
        {
            Song s = songs.get(ListMusicLibrary.getSelectedIndex());
            sid.setArtist(s.getSongArtist());
            sid.setGenre(s.getSongGenre());
            sid.setFileType(s.getFileType(AddSongDialog.getjTextFieldFileName().getText()));
        }

        sid.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        sid.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

SongInfoDialog

```
  public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public String getFileType() {
    return fileType;
}

public void setArtist(String artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
    jTextFieldArtistInfo.setText(artist);
}

public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
    jTextFieldGenreInfo.setText(genre);
}

public void setFileType(String fileType)
{
    this.fileType = fileType;
    jTextFieldFileType.setText(fileType);
}

}
```

What I am trying to do here to have the jTextFields in the SongInfoDialog display the artist, genre, and fileType information of an individual song. However, when I run the program, the jTextField for genre gets genre info and the jTextField for artist gets the songFile info. The jTextField for fileType doesn't display anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your AddSongDialog class seems to be mixing static variables (variables of a class, hence the same variable value for all instances, it's common) and instance variables (variables in every instance, hence unique for every instance and thus not common). Your getters are static methods thus using common data and your setters are instance methods thus using unique/per instance data.

Now why you would want to get/set the textfields of the dialog escapes me.

Those JTextFields should be inside your class, and instead you would have methods like

```
private JTextField filenameTextField = new JTextField();

public String getFilename() {
    return this.filenameTextField.getText();
}

public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filenameTextField.setText(filename);
}
```